# Select rows with the highest value for one ID, after grouping by two IDs

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

It is given in the problem that occurrences has to happen more than once, but the person (`PID`) should only be selected with the (agent) `AID` having the highest `BustCount`.

```
SELECT I.AgentID, I.PersonID, Count(*) AS BustCount
FROM InvolvedIn I
WHERE I.AgentID IS NOT NULL 
AND I.isCulprit = TRUE
GROUP BY I.AgentID, I.PersonID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This what I get:

```
AID     PID     BustCount 
1       11      4
2       22      2
3       22      5
4       33      5
5       44      4
```

But I would like to get only the `PID` with the highest `BustCount` (not line row 2).

```
AID     PID     BustCount 
1       11      4
3       22      5
4       33      5
5       44      4
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Any time you have a question concerning a query, it's a good idea to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for all table(s) in the query. Answers may vary depending on whether fields can be `NULL` or not and/or the precise datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding `DISTINCT ON (PersonID)` will do the job in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (PersonID)
       AgentID, PersonID, Count(*) AS BustCount
FROM   InvolvedIn i
WHERE  AgentID IS NOT NULL 
AND    isCulprit
GROUP  BY AgentID, PersonID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER  BY PersonID, BustCount DESC, AgentID;
```

I added `AgentID` as (optional) third `ORDER BY` expression and tiebreaker to get a deterministic result in case of multiple agents with the same amount of busts. Adapt to your requirements.

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

We can do all of it in a single `SELECT` without subquery, because `DISTINCT ON` is applied *after* aggregation. About the sequence of events in an `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

Oh, and `WHERE isCulprit = TRUE` is just a more noisy way of saying `WHERE isCulprit`.

Comment: Thank you, worked great! and thanks for some good recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same `AgentId` is never repeated for the same `PID` then this query should accomplish what you're looking for by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` **window function**:

```
WITH CTE_PID_HighestBustCount AS
(
     SELECT AID, PID, BustCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY BustCount DESC) AS SortId -- Generates a unique ID for each row within a PID sorted by highest BustCount first
     FROM InvolvedIn
)

SELECT AID, PID, BustCount
FROM CTE_PID_HighestBustCount
WHERE SortId = 1 -- Filter out everything except the rows with highest BustCount
```